# How do I perform print images on screen?

Tags: vb6

I am completely new to VB6, and I need to print images on a page. I am having print options in 2 different places on the same page.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to write a common method to perform the print operation:

```
Private Sub mnuPrintImage_Click()
    On Error GoTo mnuPrintImage_Click_Error

    gobjRLItemImage.PrintImage imgItem 
    Exit Sub

mnuPrintImage_Click_Error:
    ShowError "frmItem.mnuPrintImage_Click"
End Sub
```

I tried to use `Me.PrintForm`, but when I do so, I am getting a popup to save the complete page. However, I need to print the image directly and don't want to save it locally.

```
Public Sub PrintImage()
    On Error GoTo PrintImageError

    me.printform
    Exit Sub

PrintImageError:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 440:
            ' Cancel button pressed; do nothing
        Case Else
            Err.Raise Err.Number
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: *"I am completely new to VB6"* --> Unless you have a very good reason to use VB6, I suggest you start learning .NET instead (VB.NET has a similar syntax to VB6).

Comment: I agree it is very late in the day to be trying to pick up VB6, but there are plenty of alternatives worth consideration.  Don't feel that .Net is any logical inheritor of your business.

Comment: I got an issue in vb application, I am actually working on classic asp. my collegue is not available so pick up this issue. so please help me how print operation can be done in this scenario

Comment: I've removed the "VB6-express" tag, as it's not a thing and all questions that had it also had [tag:vb6]. Dinesh, can you explain how this VB6 component relates to your classic ASP? What's the type of `gobjRLItemImage`?

Comment: Do you need a "printscreen" or printing some images to paper? If the latter is the case, see the "Printer" object in VB6. It´s quite impressive what you can do on paper with few pain.